# Bank interest but reversed problem - how much was the first money deposited?

Tags: finance

Suppose I have money ($x$) in a bank account bank with compound interest of $5\%$ annually paid monthly. Bank gives me $20,000$ usd a month and the money $x$ finishes in $20$ years ($240$ months). How to calculate how much was $x$?

For example if $x=1,000,000$, after first month the money will reduce to $x'=1,000,000+1,000,000\times 0.05\times \frac{1}{12}-20,000=984,167$.

I know how to formulate it but it's very long messy equation which I have no idea how to solve it.

Thank you

Comment: In other words, an [annuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annuity)

Comment: @HenningMakholm - Yes, x will be the money if one to receive it once upfront instead of 240-month 20k-a-month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the way, $20$ years is $240$ months.

I will continue with your formulation. Let $r=1+\frac{0.05}{12}$.

After $1$ month, the bank has 
$$xr-20000$$

After $2$ month, the bank has
$$(xr-20000)r-20000=xr^2-20000r-20000$$

After $3$ months, the bank has
$$xr^3-20000r^2-20000r-20000$$

Following the pattern, after $240$ months, the bank has
$$xr^{240}-20000(1+r+r^2+\cdots r^{239})\\
=xr^{240}-20000(\frac{r^{240}-1}{r-1})$$

Can you continue from here?

Comment: Yes, I can! It will be $x=3030506$. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: @LuckyGuy: Right! Will change.

Answer (score 1):

In practice I always like to balance the equation at a certain time (usually the beginning or the end) when I did a problem about interests while I am still in high school. Let us consider the values at the end of $20$ years. How much does the $k$-th payment worth at the end of $20$ years? Imagine you put it back into deposit right after you get the payment, it should yield
$$20000 \times (1+\frac{0.05}{12})^{480-k}$$
and of course it would worth the same or otherwise you can make money by arbitrage. Therefore, this profolio worths totally
$$\sum_{k=1}^{480} 20000 \times (1+\frac{0.05}{12})^{480-k} = 20000 \times \frac{(1+\frac{0.05}{12})^{480} - 1}{(1+\frac{0.05}{12}) - 1}$$
at the end of $20$ years. On the other hand, if it worths $V$ now, it would worth
$$V \times (1+\frac{0.05}{12})^{480}$$
at the end of $20$ years. Therefore we have the equation
$$V \times (1+\frac{0.05}{12})^{480} = 20000 \times \frac{(1+\frac{0.05}{12})^{480} - 1}{(1+\frac{0.05}{12}) - 1}$$